# Why a horizontal line is not working correctly in stack bar chart

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart

I have a stacked bar chart. You can see the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/twentyTwo/mL6agyvp/466/).

I have drawn a line that is actually a horizontal line leveling the current stack of a bar. Below is the code.

.on('mouseenter', function (actual, i) {

```
          const y = yScale(actual.y + actual.y0);
                            debugger;
          line = svg.append('line')
            .attr('id', 'limit')
            .attr('x1', 0)
            .attr('y1', y)
            .attr('x2', width)
            .attr('y2', y);
```

And the output is,
[image]

Here, you can see that, for the monthly data, the line is correct. But for the quarterly data, the line is a bit above the actual position. And for the yearly data, the line is not showing.

What is the problem here?
And how can I show a tooltip along with the line?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the fiddle, it seems that the scale you are using to render the rectangles is not `yScale`, but actually just `y`

Changing the following fragment:

```
const y = yScale(actual.y + actual.y0)
line = svg.append('line')
  .attr('id', 'limit')
  .attr('x1', 0)
  .attr('y1', y)
  .attr('x2', width)
  .attr('y2', y);
```

To:

```
const limitY = y(actual.y + actual.y0);
line = svg.append('line')
  .attr('id', 'limit')
  .attr('x1', 0)
  .attr('y1', limitY)
  .attr('x2', width)
  .attr('y2', limitY);
```

Adjusts the position of the line to match the rectangles, because it is now using the same scale that the bars and the axis are using.

Regarding the tooltip, I see there is a rectangle you want to append:

```
line.append("rect")
  .attr("width", "10px")
  .attr("height", "10px")
  .style("fill", "red");
```

However, a `<line>` can not have a `<rect>` element inside. What you actually want is to add the `<rect>` to the `<svg>`:

```
svg.append("rect")
  .attr('id', 'myId') // Also give it an Id for clean up
  .attr("width", "10px")
  .attr("height", "10px")
  .attr("y", limitY) // The limitY is available to position the tooltip under the line
  .style("fill", "red");
```

Don't forget to remove it in the mouseout event, as you are doing with `<line#limit>`:

```
.on("mouseout", function() {
   svg.selectAll('#limit').remove();
   // clean the rectangle on mouseout:
   svg.selectAll('#myId').remove();
})
```

You can use the same premise of the above `<rect>` in a `<g>` element to create a full tooltip with text and background, but coding it is outside of the scope of this answer. I hope the above explanations can give you a direction.

Here is [a fiddle with the changes](https://jsfiddle.net/mhf7rgu9/8/).